# scite not showing underscores; new window will not open a new window

Tags: scite

I have noticed that, depending on enlargement scale, scite will, or wont, show underscore if not showing they are replaced by a space). Same applies to PRINT from Scite

I would say this is quite annoying as a bug for an editor....

Any clue ?

Also, when i already have an open Scite window, from the left Ubuntu Menu, selecting "new window" will not open a new window (was working with 18.04)

Tx

Ubuntu 20.04. Had not noticed that with 18.04